# Create view from table colum containing all single words of column values with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, view, dynamic-tables

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID | title
–––|–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
 1 | foxtrott uniform charlie kilo
 2 | peter parker
 3 | wulla wulla wulla
```

Now I would like to create a dynamice table or view which would look like this

```
phrase
–––––––––
charlie
foxtrott
kilo
parker
peter
uniform
wulla
```

Is this possible to do with MySQL only?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm a bit 'old school', I have a table of integers - `ints(i) [0-9]` - on my database...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'foxtrott uniform charlie kilo'),
(2,'peter parker'),
(3,'wulla wulla wulla');

 SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title,' ',i+1),' ' ,-1) n FROM my_table,ints ORDER BY n;
+----------+
| n        |
+----------+
| charlie  |
| foxtrott |
| kilo     |
| parker   |
| peter    |
| uniform  |
| wulla    |
+----------+
```